# вывод индексов граничных элементов и их значений

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Решаю задачу на алгоритмы. Текст задачи приложил в виде скрина, так как все не скопировать(сайт использует картинки на месте формул)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал сортировку слиянием:

```
public static int [] mergeSort(int lPoint, int rPoint, int[] arr)
        {
            int len = arr.Length;
            if(len == 1)
            {
                return arr;
            }
            int[] l = arr.Take(arr.Length / 2).ToArray();
            int[] r = arr.Skip(arr.Length/2).ToArray();
            l = mergeSort(1, l.Length/2, l);
            r = mergeSort(r.Length/2, r.Length, r);
            
            return mergeTwoArr(lPoint,rPoint, l, r);

            

        }
public static int[] mergeTwoArr(int l, int r,int [] arr1, int[] arr2)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;

            int[] result = new int[arr1.Length + arr2.Length];
            while (i < arr1.Length && j < arr2.Length)
            {
                if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
                {
                    result[k] = arr1[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    result[k] = arr2[j];
                    j++;
                }
                k++;

            }
            while(i < arr1.Length)
            {
                result[k] = arr1[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }
            while (j < arr2.Length)
            {
                result[k] = arr2[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
            //Console.WriteLine($"{l} {r} {result[l - 1]} {result[r - 1]}");
            return result;
            
        }
    }
```

Но я не могу понять, как правильно вывести индексы граничных элементов. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать

Comment: То ли лыжи не едут, то ли у вас в условии черным по белому написано, как именно, и даже с примерами. Мне например сложно объяснить понятнее, чем там написано. Перечитайте условие задачи.

Comment: @aepot,да,задание понятно, пример тоже, но не понимаю, как это описать в коде

Comment: Вы не в том методе вывод пытаетесь сделать. Нужно перед `return` в другом методе.

Comment: @aepot,все равно  получается не то, что нужно

Comment: Осталось только догадаться, что именно?

Comment: @aepot, поставил строчку "Console.WriteLine($"{l} {r} {result[l - 1]} {result[r - 1]}");"туда, куда вы сказали, на массиве  {1 8 2 1 4 7 3 2 3 6} выводит вот это:https://ibb.co/gWVHhZ9, а должно:https://ibb.co/NLXvGVb 
"

Comment: Попробуйте с помощью отладки и пошагового выполнения кода понять, почему.